# What if the system crashes if I have made transactions after my backup?

Tags: backup, wallet.dat, loss

Suppose I have a recent backup of my `wallet.dat` file.

Now I make (say) two transactions: one receipt and one send.

Before I run my next backup, the hard drive crashes and I lose `wallet.dat`.

I can restore `wallet.dat`, of course, but only prior to the new two transactions.

What will happen to those two transactions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you had a chance to send those transaction out, they will still be processed. So long as the transactions didn't create any new change addresses, your wallet will still have all the information needed to spend any Bitcoins you have left.

Comment: If one of those received transaction is with newly created address, still it can be recovered with old wallet file??

Comment: It depends what you mean by "newly created". If you mean you've never used it before, but it was already in the wallet, then you're fine. If the wallet ran out of extra addresses and had to create a truly new one, then no. That's why you should make sure you have 100 or so extra addresses in your wallet when you back it up.